# I have to write settesting(true) to adding admob ad?

Tags: android, admob

I want to add admob ad.so I must write this code

```
 request.setTesting(true);
```

or it does not necessary.

Comment: I don't understand your question entirely. Are you not receiving ads unless you set it as testing?

Comment: my ads is allright. but ı want to know this line is necessary or dont

Comment: It is not, but you should set your device up as a test device. Like @Tim said, you can be accused of fraud.

Comment: if I set test mode to true when my app on market ,this is bad? ı dont get money or dont necessary.

Comment: I use my app and I see real app and in admob my revenue grow up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the developer guide?

http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1704625

If you don't set test mode to true during development, you will be receiving live ads on your phone during development. It might not sound like a big deal, but I'd imagine if you make too many ad pulls using your development device you could be investigated for fraud and have your admob account suspended.

Also running in non-test mode may not always return an ad, which might not be good for testing.

Comment: My ads is work.But I want to know request.setTesting(true); is necessary or dont

Comment: if I set test mode to true when my app on market ,this is bad? or dont necessary

Comment: If you release a version of your app on the market with test mode on, you won't get any money, because all your users will see fake ads.

Comment: but tim I use my app and I see real app and in admob my revenue grow up ?